# How to add div inside a div - Like a nest - using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add Subsection To a Section and Item to a Subsection using Jquery

Every Item to a subsection is unique to its parent. I have done something close but i am unable to add item under newly added subsection.

```
                $(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#subRootItems');
        var i = $('#subRootItems').size() + 1;

        $('#addSubFOODItem').live('click', function() {
                $('<div class="menuItemContainer"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Item Name" name="foodItemName'+ i +'" class="itemFieldEdit"><div class="itemPrice"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Price" name="foodItemName' + i +'" class="priceInput"></div><div class="actionItemBox"><div class="homeLBoxRightEdit" id="remItem"><i class="icon-trash" id="remSubFoodItem">REMOVE ITEM</i></div></div></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#remSubFoodItem').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('.menuItemContainer').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#menuSubSection');
        var i = $('#menuSubSection').size() + 1;

        $('#addSubSection').live('click', function() {
                $('<div class="menuSubCategoryTitle"><div class="menuCategoryTitle"><div style="float: left;"><i class="icon-menu" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Vegetarian</div><div class="menuEditIcons"><a href="#"><i class="icon-plus-1" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon-trash" id="delSubSection">REMOVE SUB SECTION</i></a></div></div><div class="addMenuBtns"><div class="visualMenuBtn" id="addSubFOODItem"><i class="icon-food-1" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>New Food-Item</div></div></div><div id="subRootItems"></div><div class="clear"></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#delSubSection').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('.menuSubCategoryTitle').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
    });
```

Please take a look : http://jsfiddle.net/AnmQy/

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `$('#addSubFOODItem').live('click', function() { .... });` of the code with the below mentioned code and check whether it meet to your requirements.

```
$('#addSubFOODItem').live('click', function () {
                var SubFoodItemDiv = $(this).parents("div.menuSubCategoryTitle");
                $('<div class="menuItemContainer"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Item Name" name="foodItemName' + i + '" class="itemFieldEdit"><div class="itemPrice"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Price" name="foodItemName' + i + '" class="priceInput"></div><div class="actionItemBox"><div class="homeLBoxRightEdit" id="remItem"><i class="icon-trash" id="remSubFoodItem">REMOVE ITEM</i></div></div></div>').appendTo(SubFoodItemDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
            });
```

Let me know if your requirement is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are always adding them to `#subRootItems` which is the 1st one. Essentially you need unique IDs for the DIVs.

Comment: the Div can be auto increment but the in the js functioni cannot :(

Like if i add `#addSubFOODItem+i+` in html but i cannot specify in  the js onclick event

Comment: add the "addItem" button to the subcategory, so you can use "this" as the context